# Load a php file that contains echo in a div without reload

Tags: php, ajax, load, echo

I can't manage to load a php file that contains echo in a div without reload..
This is my php file

```
<?php
    $images = get_field('gallery');
    if ( $images ) : ?>
        <ul class="grid" >
          <li class="grid-sizer"></li><!-- for Masonry column width -->
          <?php foreach( $images as $image ) : ?>
            <li><figure><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" /></figure></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

This is my div

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

And I tried with this javascript

```
$.ajax({
     type : 'GET',
     url : 'file.php',
     success : function(data){

          $('#container').html(data);
     },
```

But only html elements are loaded..
Thanks,

Comment: Change the filename to `file.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use more simple code like this:

```
<?php $images = get_field('gallery');
   if ( $images ) { 
?>
     <ul class="grid" >
        <li class="grid-sizer"></li><!-- for Masonry column width -->
           <?php 
              foreach( $images as $image ) { ?>
                 <li>
                    <figure>
                      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
                    </figure>
                 </li>
              <?php }; ?>
        </li>
     </ul>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that $images is array? Try to check it with `is_array($images)`

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `load()`;

```
$('#container').load('file.php');
```

Comment: What does it return @user3334919? It is awfully unusual for PHP not to process the HTML and return it. Where is `get_field()` defined?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention this, I use a worpress administration plugin, get_field allows to retrieve several images on data base..

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code with some changes for e.g. added the script in php file on purpose, closed brackets of ajax function and passed data through ajax function.

In one php file say script.php

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
     type : 'GET',
     images : '<?php echo get_field('gallery');?>',
     url : 'file.php',
     success : function(data){

          $('#container').html(data);
     }
});
});
</script>
```

And in file.php

```
<?php $images =  $_GET['images'];
    if ( $images ) : ?>
                    <ul class="grid" >
                        <li class="grid-sizer"></li><!-- for Masonry column width -->
                        <?php foreach( $images as $image ) : ?>
                        <li><figure><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" /></figure></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It still not work, maybe it is because of my wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#refreshh').click(function(){
     $('#container').load('file.php');// (get_field etc.)
});
```

Do you want something like this?

but, Your 'file.php' can have all params